# select and unselect all checkboxes doesn't work when implementing javascript script

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, lightbox, selected

my code:

```
<body>
    <input type="button" class="btn-primary btn-mini" id="check1" value="Check All" /> 
    <input type="hidden" id="isChkd" value="true"/> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="cb1-element"> <a href="../upload/Zdjecia-0006.jpg" data-lightbox='image'><img src='../upload/Zdjecia-0002.jpg' height=50/></a>        
    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="cb1-element"> <a href="../upload/Zdjecia-0008.jpg" data-lightbox='image'><img src='../upload/Zdjecia-0008.jpg' height=50/></a>
    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="cb1-element"> <a href="../upload/Zdjecia-0004.jpg" data-lightbox='image'><img src='../upload/Zdjecia-0004.jpg' height=50/></a>                                                                 
    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="cb1-element"> <a href="../upload/Zdjecia-0005.jpg" data-lightbox='image'><img src='../upload/Zdjecia-0005.jpg' height=50/></a>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#check1').click(function(){
            if($('#isChkd').val() == 'true'){
                $('.cb1-element').attr('checked','checked');
                $(this).val('Uncheck All');
                $('#isChkd').val('false');
            }
            else{
                $('.cb1-element').removeAttr('checked');
                $(this).val('Check All');     
                $('#isChkd').val('true');
            }
        });

        $('.cb1-element').change(function(){
            var all = $('input.cb1-element').length;
            var checked = $('input.cb1-element:checked').length;
            if(all == checked){
                $('#check1').val('Uncheck All');
                $('#isChkd').val('false');
            }else{
                $('#check1').val('Check All');
                $('#isChkd').val('true');
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

When I adding "../js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" checking script working only once (when i clicked more than 2 times nothing happen). When I removing "../js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" checking script working but the lightBox deosnt' work. Anybody knows something about this problem?

Comment: Always wrap your jQuery DOM manipulations in `$(document.ready(function() { });`

Answer (score 0):

first of all include your code inside `$(document).ready()`

Then to check all try instead of this:

```
$('.cb1-element').attr('checked','checked');
```

this:

```
$('.cb1-element').attr('checked',true);
```

and to uncheck all try this:

```
$('.cb1-element').attr('checked',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are including jquery script twice in your page. One on line number 8 as:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and second on line number 35 as:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Try removing the first jquery script tag, and replace it with the second one (i.e. replace line number 8 with line number 35)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working code.I have checked it at my end.If you need then can make a jsbin for the same .

```
$('#check1').click(function() {
        if ($('#isChkd').val() == 'true') {
            $('.cb1-element').prop('checked', true);
            $(this).val('Uncheck All');
            $('#isChkd').val('false');
        } else {
            $('.cb1-element').prop('checked', false);
            $(this).val('Check All');
            $('#isChkd').val('true');
        }
});
```